# Microsoft Graph API get users Source name (Provider name)?

Tags: c#, azure-ad-graph-api

Microsoft Graph API how to get users Source name (Provider name) in C# `AzureGraphClient`?

[image]

Comment: @TonyJu, I'm sorry, but in fact your answer does not solve the problem.

Comment: But currently we can not get the source name. You can refer to the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently user source is not returned by the Microsoft Graph API. All the properties the Graph API returned are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties).

You may leave your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/38373556-b2b-please-expose-the-source-property-in-the-gr) and upvote for the same. All the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.

You can also refer to [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/60b437c7-4bb5-4985-ac30-365eb6e46a7a/how-to-access-source-property-on-azure-ad-user-profile?forum=WindowsAzureAD) for more details.